# Extending object scope out of if statement

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I have the following C++ design problem.

Suppose I have the following class:

```
class Model {
  Model(int numberOfModels, int flag=-1) : 
    _models(numberOfModels), _flag(flag){ }

  void buildModel(){
    for (int id=0; id<_models.size(); ++id) {
      if (flag == -1){
        BuilderOne builder;
        builder.build(&_models[id]);
      }
      else {
        BuilderTwo builder;
        builder.build(&_models[id]);
      }
    }
  } 

  private:
    vector<SimpleModel> _models;
    int _flag;
};
```

where the member function "buildModel" builds a vector of "SimpleModel" object. "BuilderOne" and "BuilderTwo" are different builder class which all implements a "build" method (or they can be inherited from the same BaseBuilder class using CRTP).

But the above implementation is quite cumbersome, since the type of builder should be predetermined by "_flag" before entering the loop. What I really want is the following implementation of "buildModel" method:

```
void buildModel(){
  if (flag == -1){
    BuilderOne builder;
  else
    BuilderTwo builder;

  for (int id=0; id<_models.size(); ++id)
    builder.build(&_models[id]);       
}
```

However, the above code doesn't compile because 1) object "builder" is not visible after the if statement 2) type of the "builder" cannot be decided at compile time.

The above functionality can easily be realized by making the "build" method a **virtual function** in a BaseBuilder. But virtually function is not considered as a solution because of various reasons in our library. But inheritance (like CRTP) would be acceptable.

Some one could help to get around with this problem?

Comment: Virtual functions are not a solution? What kind of silliness is that?

Comment: Store a function pointer in the object instead of `_flag`.  At construction, point it to the correct builder.

Comment: make `buildModel` templated, and call the appropriate instantiation.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention, the buildModel interface cannot be changed, templating it either require pass in additional parameter for deduction or add template argument.

Answer (score 1):

With the [insane] *requirement* that virtual functions cannot be used your current implementation is just broken. Every time a new builder type is added you will have to update your `Model` class. This may be exactly what you want (your post is unclear on this) so I'll try to cover both approaches with a single solution.

First you can start by taking advantage of static polymorphism and place the main functionality in a function template. This will help you get around the lack of virtual functions in reducing the amount of code necessary to use it.

```
class Model
{
public:
    template<class BuilderType>
    BuilderType buildModel()
    {
        BuilderType builder;

        //  Perform other tasks here

        for (int id = 0; id<_models.size(); ++id)
        {
            builder.build(&_models[id]);
        }

        //  Perform other tasks here

        return builder;
    }
};
```

This will allow you to use object type as long as it implements a `build` function that takes a pointer to an instance of `SimpleModel`. You also have the option of taking a builder as an argument to the function which will allow automatic type deduction. Whether you make it public, private, or protected is up to you and how you decide to move forward. This may be all that you need but if you want to limit the `buildModel` function to a specific set of builders you can make it protected or private and provide a public function that simplifies the building process.

```
class Model
{
public:
    void buildModel()
    {
        switch (flag_)
        {
        case -1:
            buildModelByType<BuilderOne>(b);
            break;

        default:
            buildModelByType<BuilderTwo>(b);
            break;
        }
    }

protected:

    template<class BuilderType>
    BuilderType buildModelByType()
    {
        BuilderType builder;

        //  Perform other tasks here

        for (int id = 0; id<_models.size(); ++id)
        {
            builder.build(&_models[id]);
        }

        //  Perform other tasks here

        return builder;
    }
};
```

Whether you take the builders by argument or return the result of the building process is up to you. Your post wasn't specific about that aspect of the problem but this should be easily adaptable to whatever you're towards.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention, the signature of "buildModel" cannot be changed. Your second solution looks promising. I'll take a try.